# Mobile Safari Notifying

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I have a html5/JavaScript app. I would like to notify the user when a countdown timer runs out.

The problem is mobile safari. It looks like (unless I'm a native app) I.

- Can't play a sound by itself (apparently mobile Safari requires sound to be played on user action (to prevent unwanted bandwidth consumption I'm guessing)
- Can't vibrate phone (window.navigator.mozVibrate(pattern) does not appear to work)
- Can't flash the screen with some colors because the screen will typically go off after 30 seconds (and I can't tell the screen to turn on if it's off in mobile safari either)
- Can't send itself a notification

Heck, is there anything I can do without forcing the user to download a native application? Any type of cue or indication to look at the phone?

Comment: I'd say you're out of luck. That's simply not what websites are, at least on mobile.